# how to fix errors in this program and why i m getting it?

Tags: c++, c, c++11

The errors are:

- reference to 'name' is ambiguous
- reference to 'age' is ambiguous
- request for member 'input1' is ambiguous
- no matching function for call to 'ashish3::inputage()'

Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

class ashish
{
protected:
    string name;
public:
    void input1(string name1)
    {
        cin >> name1;
        name = name1;
    }

    int age;
};

class ashish2 : public ashish
{
public:
    void inputage(int age1)
    {
        cin >> age1;
        age = age1;
    }

    void display()
    {
        cout << name;
    }
};

class ashish3 : public ashish, public ashish2
{
public:
    void showme()
    {
        cout << "the name is" << name << endl << "the age is " << age << endl;
    }
};

int main()
{
    ashish3 rocker;
    rocker.input1();
    rocker.inputage();
    rocker.display();
    rocker.showme();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried Hello World?

Comment: Everything is wrong in this code

Comment: The error messages actually explain, if you take the time to work through them one-by-one.

Comment: If you indent your code properly more people may find it easier to help you.

Comment: `compiler: unknown` Get a compiler

Comment: You should remove the `C` tag because `class` is not a reserved word in the C language. They are different languages.  Similarly with `public` and inheritance.

Comment: If you are programming in C, you will need to handle `operator <<`.  Overloading is not allowed in C, so the `<<` operator is performing a *shift* operator and shifting by text doesn't make sense.  I recommend switching to a C++ compiler and removing the `C` tag.

Answer (score 1):

There are two major problems with your code:

1. Your `inputage` method expects an integer, but you call it with no parameters. To fix it, just make `age1` a local variable instead of a parameter (there's no reason for it to be a parameter).
2. Your `ashish3` class inherits from both `ashish` and `ashish2`. By inheriting from `ashish2` it also inherits from `ashish` one more time, since `ashish2` on itself inherits from `ashish`, resulting in inheriting from `ashish` twice. Thus, all the members of `ashish` exist in `ashish3` twice, causing the first three ambiguity errors. To get around it, only inherit `ashish3` from `ashish2` (`class ashish3 : public ashish2`).

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

class ashish
{
protected:
    string name;
public:
    void input1(string name1) {
        cin >> name1;
        name = name1;
    }
    int age;
};
class ashish2 :public ashish
{
public:
    void inputage(int age1) {
        cin >> age1;
        age = age1;
    }
    void display()
    {
        cout << name;
    }
};
class ashish3 : public ashish2
{
public:
    void showme()
    {
        cout << "the name is" << name << endl << "the age is " << age << endl;
    }
};
int main()
{
    ashish3 rocker;
    rocker.input1("xasdas");
    rocker.inputage(123);
    rocker.display();
    rocker.showme();
    return 0;
}
```

You got a few errors, you did not call your functions with parameters. You did not add a `<string>` header which you should add. And you should not make ashish3 inherit from both of ashish1 and ashish2, because ashish2 inherits all functions and variables as ashish class. C++ is a different language than C please delete the C tag.